# how to fetch data using Rest API in spring boot from multiple tables

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jpa, crud

hello am new to coding and am trying to create a rest api in spring boot that fetches data from 4 tables in the database which uses one query to return the result set. How can i do this.

Comment: always add some of the code which you have already tried and didn't worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a native SQL query, but the use case mentioned can be easily achieved with HQL. Before that, let's use the proper annotations mappings for ManytoMany association:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_detail")
public class OrderDetail {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     private Integer id;


     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name="purchased_By")
     private user PurchasedBy;


     @ManyToMany
     @JoinTable(
       name="order_detail_productlist",
       joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="order_detail_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
       inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="productlist_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
      private Set<Product> productlist = new HashSet<Product>();
```

Product

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="product")
public class Product implements Serializable {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      private Integer id;

      @NotNull(message = "Product name must not be null")
      @NotEmpty
      @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
      private String name;


      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name="category_id")
      private Category category;

      @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "productlist")
      private List<OrderDetail> orderDetail =new ArrayList<OrderDetail>();
```

```
public final static String product_ordered ="Select p from Product p Join p.orderDetail od Where od.id = :id";

@Query(product_ordered)
public List<Product> findById(@Param("id") int id);
```

for more read [here](https://www.javaworld.com/article/3379043/what-is-jpa-introduction-to-the-java-persistence-api.html)